# Ext-JS 4 border layout inside card layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am creating an application with Ext-JS 4.

Cards:

1.) Login card

2.) Application card

Application card has a **border** layout.

When I show them separately, they work but when I put them in a Viewport together, they don't work.

Here is my **Viewport**:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'card',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'loginform',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'mainapp'
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is a part of my **Login card**:

```
Ext.define('Sabrina.view.login.Form' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
    alias : 'widget.loginform',

    name: 'loginform',
    frame: true,
    title: 'Login',
    bodyPadding: '5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    ...
```

Here is a part of my **Application card**:

```
Ext.define('Sabrina.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: ['widget.mainapp'],
    layout: 'border',
        items: [
          //here I have 'west' and 'center' regions
        ]
```

I've created the same components in a different application **separately** and they work but here not. Do I have to put something more if I want a **border** layout inside **card** layout?

I'm getting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Why don't you show a login window as modal? Using a card layout for just login and then the actual app is overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for response. Can you explain "window as modal"? Where and how should I put it (some beforeRender)? Do you have code examples somewhere? (I've Googled it already.) :D

Comment: You should look at the **[API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window)** cause **[modal](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-modal)** is a property

Comment: It restricts access to the other components.

Comment: +1 for help. Modal solves my problem. Thank you. :)

Comment: @JohanHaest You can copy your first comment and post it as answer so I can mark it as "accepted answer". :)

Comment: Ok, did you manage to fix it like that?

Comment: Well... I've wrote the new layout with 2 items: myApp and window (which is modal) so the window doesn't go away until you log in. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you show a login window as modal? Using a card layout for just login and then the actual app is overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

viewport can only handle one element, while cardlayout manages many with only one active. Make the only element of the viewport a container with cardlayout and give the viewport a fitlayout, that should work.

Your error sounds more like unknown xtypes. Anyway, try the descriped layout, maybe the error is gone.